# how can convert my SQL to Laravel Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
SELECT count(ip) AS failed_attempts
FROM login_attempts
WHERE ip = $ip
  AND date < (NOW - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use eloquent not Query builder

Its easy using eloquent. I recomen read all documentation about https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Assuming you have a model LoginAttempt. You just have to do this:

```
// Eloquent
$failedAttempts = LoginAttempt::where('ip', $ip)
    ->where('date', '<', now()->subHours(24))->count();
```

Or if your prefer you can use Query Builder:

```
// Query builder
$failedAttempts = \DB::table('login_attempts')->where('ip', $ip)
    ->where('date', '<', now()->subHours(24))->count();
```